# How do I get a dummy database to test my Rails 3.2 engine using minitest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, minitest

I'm working on an existing Rails 3.2 site and have been tasked with adding tests to one of the engines using Minitest.  My underlying issue here is that there are no rake tasks available beyond `rake test`.  Running anything in this engine's directory will result in the error:

`rake aborted!`

`Don't know how to build task '[insert task here]'`

Therefore, I have no access to db:create, db:test:prepare, etc.  I've manually created the test database and one of the tables.  However, for all my tests, I now receive the following error:
`SQLite3::SQLException: no such table ...` even though the table is in the database and there are fixtures available.  How do I get a working dummy database?

Comment: Have you tried prepending your command with `bundle exec`? E.g. `bundle exec rake db:create`

Comment: I have.  Same effect.

Comment: Just for confirmation. Where did you set database.yml. You set it in ./config or ./test/dummy/config?

Comment: I have it set in both places.

Comment: whats the content in your database.yml file? try this command:  ruby -I test test/unit/my_model_test.rb -n test_name.